# Tracking anonymous users in Angular app

Tags: django, angularjs, single-page-application, restful-authentication

I am working on SPA AngularJS application which allows users to collaborate on projects and stores history of edits for each user. The requirement is to allow unauthenticated users to manipulate data too. Once the user registers, I need to associate her history of edits with the newly created account. The backend is Django.
What is the best option to track actions of anonymous users?

1. I can create “anonymous” user at the firs visit, issue JWT, store it in the browser and use to track all the user’s activity. Later on when registering user, just update her profile.
   The drawback is that there is a potential to get a lot of orphaned users that need to be periodically cleaned up.
   This is similar to https://github.com/danfairs/django-lazysignup, but adapted to work with https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt.
2. Use JWT or cookie to track user session. Allow using session identifier instead of user key to track user’s activity. When creating real user update all references to the session with user’s pk.

Anything else?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience go for solution 1. The orphan user is often not a problem because from business plan point of view it's user and the more is better.

Also having only a notion of user is really simpler. They are users who haven't fully completed their profile that's all.

Comment: Thanks! It was my inclination too, just wanted to make sure there is no other standard mechanism to use.